# Special path of vim swap files for files in certain location

Tags: vim, swapfile

Due to my configuration, vim stores swap files in the same directory as the edited file. In general, that is ok, but not in the folder `~/ftp_mount` (and all directories below). In this directory I mount an ftp server.

With

> :set dir=/some/path

one can change the location in which vim stores the swap files ([vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27directory%27)). Is it possible to restrict this configuration to `~/ftp_mount` and all directories below?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

How about using an autocmd on the directory you want to apply this setting to (`~/ftp_mount`)

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead ~/ftp_mount/* set dir=/some/path
```

Comment: It would be great if this worked, but it seems that the `autocmd` happens after the swapfile has been set.

You can see this by looking at the value of `:set directory` (which has the value set by the autocmd), and the value of `:swapname`  (which has a value corresponding to the default value of `directory`).

(edit) The answer is pretty old, perhaps the behaviour changed in a more recent version of Vim?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling swapfile, setting directory, and enabling it back seems to work:

```
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPre *
        \ setl noswapfile noundofile |
        \ if expand('%:p') =~ "/my/custom/path" |
        \   setl undodir=. directory=. |
        \ else |
        \   setl undodir=~/.cache/nvim/undo directory=~/.cache/nvim/swap |
        \ endif |
        \ setl swapfile undofile
```

I am matching `*`, not my path particularly, because I want it to work if I:

1. Open a file under my custom path.
2. Load a new file from elsewhere.